# Como alterar a seleção entre duas checkbox?

Tags: javascript

Preciso realizar a seleção de duas checkbox, quando eu clicar em uma a outra não é selecionada, e quando a outra for selecionada essa anterior não pode ser selecionada, podendo selecionar apenas uma.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
                workerWOReprogram.sisteplant_CBReprogPeriod_OnChangeValue = function(oCheck, isChecked)
            {
                console.log("sisteplant_CBReprogPeriod_OnChangeValue");

                if(isChecked)
                     scr.setValue("CBReprogWO", false);         
                else scr.setValue("CBReprogPeriod", true);

                var RSWorkOrder = scr.getObject("RSWorkOrder");
                var RSWorker    = scr.getObject("RSWorker");
                RSWorkOrder.setSelectionType(SELECTIONTYPE.All);
                RSWorker.setSelectionType(SELECTIONTYPE.All);
            }

            workerWOReprogram.sisteplant_CBReprogWO_OnChangeValue = function(oCheck, isChecked)
            {
                console.log("sisteplant_CBReprogWO_OnChangeValue");

                if(isChecked)
                     scr.setValue("CBReprogPeriod", false);
                else scr.setValue("CBReprogWO", true); 

                var RSWorkOrder = scr.getObject("RSWorkOrder");
                var RSWorker    = scr.getObject("RSWorker");
                RSWorkOrder.setSelectionType(SELECTIONTYPE.All);
                RSWorker.setSelectionType(SELECTIONTYPE.All);
            }
```

Esse é meu código, porém ja vasculhei tudo e não sei onde errei!

Antes apenas uma era selecionada, agora consigo selecionar ambas, e não é isso que quero.

Alguém consegue me ajudar? HTML ABAIXO

```
            <fieldset name="LabelAndCheckBoxes_fieldset">
              <checkbox labelText="_T(F_REPROG_PERIOD)" name="CBReprogPeriod" defaultValue="1" />
              <checkbox labelText="_T(F_REPROG_WO)" name="CBReprogWO" defaultValue="0" />
            </fieldset>
```

Comment: Não seria melhor por `radio` ao invés de `checkbox`?

Comment: @LaércioLopes, foi solicitado a utilização de checkbox

Comment: @LeAndrade, isso não funcionou no meu caso

Comment: Pq não funcionou, qual o problema que teve?

Comment: Não consigo repassar o exemplo para o meu problema

Comment: O mais correto seria postar o seu **Html** e o código **JS** em questão completos.

Comment: @LeAndrade postei